# Ionic 2 angularfire2 Auth

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, observable, angularfire2

I am having an issue when subscribing to angularfire auth. Basically whats going on is when I subscribe like so: `this.af.auth.first().subscribe(auth => { console.log(auth) })` auth is printed to the console twice instead of just once. I think I found the cause of this issue but I don't understand why its happening or what to do about it. In my app.component.ts I am subscribing to auth also like so:

```
this.af.auth.first().subscribe(auth => {
  console.log("app")
  if (auth) {
    console.log('logged in');
    this.rootPage = "page1"
  } else {
    console.log('not logged in');
    this.rootPage = "login"
  }

})
```

If I remove this subscription then then I only have one print to console from the above subscription. I want to be able to subscribe in both these locations so when the app is loaded I can redirect to login if need be and also be able to grab the users uid in the application from the other subscription. If you have any idea that would be great, thank you!

Comment: Where do you call this method? inside the `constructor` or else?

Comment: In the app.Component.ts it's called in ngOnInit(). The other subscription is called from ionViewDidLoad() in a page. If I'm being exacts it's a function in a provider is making the subscription then that providers function is called in the page's ionViewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

You have to call this inside the `constructor` as shown below.And also `unsubscribe` after that.

***app.component.ts***

```
constructor(platform: Platform, af: AngularFire) {
    const authListener = af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
       if (auth) {
        console.log('logged in');
        this.rootPage = "page1";
        authListener.unsubscribe();//unsubscribe here
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        this.rootPage = "login";
        authListener.unsubscribe();//unsubscribe here
      }
    });

    platform.ready().then(() => {

    });
  }
```

Comment: If you refresh the page means it creates page again and prints console again..You can do this only on the browser.On the real device, you cannot do this.Hence no problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried that and it didn't work for me. Here's what I did in the app.component.ts

```
constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    const authListener = af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        console.log('logged in');
        this.rootPage = "page-conversations"
        authListener.unsubscribe();//unsubscribe here
      } else {
        console.log('not logged in');
        this.rootPage = "page-login"
        authListener.unsubscribe();//unsubscribe here
      }
    });
    this.initializeApp();
  }
```

Then here is what I did in the page

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
         console.log("auth hello")
    })
  }
```

Still had two console logs.

**UPDATE**
So I found out what the issue is. I believe it is because of deep linking. When I load the page I am determined as logged in so I am redirect to another page. This changes the url to: `http://localhost:8100/#/page-conversations` then when I refresh the page the url is the same so that page is loaded but my app.component.ts also determines I'm logged in so I am redirected to the page I'm already on. That is why there is duplicate calls. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this so it will not happen?

Comment: So I just noticed when i first load the page there is only one console log but if i refresh there is two. Could this be because of improper clean up of the subscriptions? The issue continues until i stop the page and redo an ionic serve.